# Undefined function 'linprog' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab, linear-programming

Trying to solve a linear programming problem:
Input:

```
  c = [2 3 -4 0 0]
Aeq = [1 1 1 0 0; 2 -1 0 1 0; 1 2 -1 0 1]
beq = [2;4;5]
lb  = [0;0;0;0;0]

x=linprog(c,[],[],Aeq,beq,lb,[])
```

And get this error:

```
Undefined function 'linprog' for input arguments of type'double'.
```

What do I have to do to make the function work? I have Matlab R2013a, installed only Matlab 8.1 from programs list.

Comment: `linprog` is in the optimization toolbox, do you have it installed? Type `ver` in the command line to see a list of your toolboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`linprog` is part of the optimization toolbox, type in `ver` to the available toolboxes. If you don't have a license which includes the toolbox, you can't use it.